# Neo4J traversal in correct order for two different relationships?

Tags: neo4j

I'm using the Neo4J Traversal API and trying to traverse from "1" to find nodes "2" and "3" fitting the pattern below:

```
1-[:A]-2-[:B]-3
```

However, in my traversal, I'm getting caught out because the following relationship also exists:

```
1-[:B]-3
```

As far as I understand, my `TraversalDescription` needs to specify both relationship types, but I'm unsure of the most elegant way to traverse the :A relationship first, and then branch out to the :B relationship. Unfortunately the relationship `Direction` can't be used to differentiate in my case.

My Scala code is:

```
db.traversalDescription()
    .evaluator(isAThenBRelationship)
    .breadthFirst()
    .relationships(A)
    .relationships(B)

private val isAThenBRelationship = new PathEvaluator.Adapter() {
override def evaluate(path: Path, state: BranchState[Nothing]): Evaluation = {
  if (path.length == 0) {
    EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE
  } else if (path.length == 1) {
    Evaluation.of(false, path.relationships().iterator().next().getType.name() == A.toString)
  } else {
    Evaluation.of(path.relationships().iterator().next().getType.name() == B.toString, false)
  }
}
```

}

As an aside, what's a better way of comparing relationships than this?

```
path.relationships().iterator().next().getType.name() == MyRelationship.toString
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `relationships()` multiple times does not imply an order. Instead there is a internal list which `relationships()` adds something to.

To limit a certain relationship type to a certain depth, you need to implement and use your own `PathExpander`. The example below uses Java and implements the `PathExpander` using an anonymous inner class:

```
traversalDescription.expand(new PathExpander<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Iterable<Relationship> expand(Path path, BranchState<Object> state) {
        switch (path.length()) {
            case 0:
                return path.endNode().getRelationships(
                    DynamicRelationshipType.withName("A") );
            case 1:
                return path.endNode().getRelationships(
                    DynamicRelationshipType.withName("B") );
            default:
                return Iterables.empty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PathExpander<Object> reverse() {
        // not used for unidirectional traversals
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
});
```

### Regarding your second question:

Neo4j contains a very convenient class `IteratorUtils`. With that your snippet can be written as (assuming MyRelationship is a instance of `RelationshipType`:

```
 IteratorUtil.first(path.relationships()).getType().equals(MyRelationship)
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to @StefanArmbruster's answer, here's the equivalent Scala code:

```scala
db.traversalDescription()
  .breadthFirst()
  .expand(isAThenBRelationship)

private val isAThenBRelationship = 
   new PathExpander[Object]() {
     override def expand(path: Path, state: BranchState[Object]) =
       path.length() match {
         case 0 => path.endNode().getRelationships(DynamicRelationshipType.withName("A"))
         case 1 => path.endNode().getRelationships(DynamicRelationshipType.withName("B"))
         case _ => Iterables.empty()
       }

     override def reverse(): PathExpander[Object] = ???
   }
```

Note that the expander must come after the relationships.

Comment: you can omit the calls to `relationships()` method.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster thanks. I have updated my answer. Please keep the helpful comments coming - I'm keen to improve my Neo & Scala.

Comment: in most cases TraversalDescription needs an evaluator that decides if a certain path is part of the result set. I'm not sure what happens if you omit specifying an evaluator, either you get all traversed paths as result or none.